# A probability inequality: $p+(1-p)E[v|v\geq a] \geq E[v|v \geq p+(1-p)a]$

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities

There is a random variable $v \sim F(\cdot)$ with support $[0,1]$. For a parameter $p \in (0,1)$ and $a \in (0,1)$. Define $A$ and $B$ as the following:
$$A=p+(1-p)E[v|v\geq a], B=E[v|v \geq p+(1-p)a]$$

My question is: What is the relationship between $A$ and $B$?

My conjecture is $A \geq B$, but how to show it or turn it over?

Answer (score 2):

The conjecture is not true. You may have either $A>B$ or $A<B$ depending on the distribution of the random variable, which I will denote by $V$ (rather than $v$), according to the standard convention.

Indeed, letting 
$$T(a):=E(V|V\ge a)
$$
for $a\in[0,1)$ and assuming that the point $1$ is in the support set of the distribution of $V$, we see that $T(1-)=1$ and hence 
$$A=(1-p)T(a)+pT(1-),\quad B=T((1-p)a+p). 
$$
So, we will have $A>B$ if $T$ is strictly convex and $A<B$ if $T$ is strictly concave.

Now suppose that $V$ has the pdf $f=f_t$ such that $f_t(v)=(1+t)v^t$ for a real $t>-1$ and all $v\in(0,1]$.

If now $t=1$, then $T(a)=\frac{2 \left(a^2+a+1\right)}{3 (a+1)}$ and $T''(a)=\frac{4}{3 (a+1)^3}>0$ for $a\in(0,1)$, so that $T$ is strictly convex and hence $A>B$. If $t=-1/2$, then $T(a)=(1 +a+\sqrt a\,)/3$ for $a\in(0,1)$, so that $T$ is strictly concave and hence $A<B$.